# how to test mobile application which uses wifi connection?

Tags: test-design, android, mobile

I need to test the application, which was working based on the WiFi signal strength.

Is there any `application/automation tool` to randomize my `WiFi` signal and check for applications functionality, my application need to be tested with varied WiFi signal strengths.

Please share your thoughts to test mobile application, which uses WiFi connection.

My applications functionality is as follows

1. Its an multiplayer gaming application, which allows users to play through `WiFi mode`, i.e up to 5 number of users can login and play the game.
2. it's an `android mobile` multiplayer game

I considered the above questions under this criteria:

1. The users with varied WiFi limit(speed) some devices may vary on speed, signal strength etc.
2. I will play the game through WiFi so I wish to test the application based on the WiFi connection speed, latency etc.

Comment: Have you considered a big room and slowly backing away? :-)

Comment: Do you really want to randomize the signal, or do you want to completely control it, with the ability to vary the signal strength?  Randomizing the signal does not seem like the best approach for testing purposes, while varying the signal could be useful.

Comment: @SamWoods varying signals,how can i do it i dont have any idea on it :( can you provide any reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a mobile application, presumably you have the handset to test it on (my old mobile shop had every handset in-house...quite an inventory).  You should physically move around to get varying WiFi signal strengths.

If you don't want to use your feet, you can begin wrapping aluminum foil around the handset until the signal dies down, or throw it in a Hoffman box if you have one of those handy.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use a variable attenuator between your device and AP, there are manual and controllable models and it's relatively cheap.
   You'll have to connect it to the Wi Fi antennas using an RF cable , or put your device into an RF insulated box, which in turn is connected to the attenuator.
2. Your application probably doesn't see the signal strength reports directly, you can mock the OS calls to mimic variable signal strengths.
3. Look for a WiFi signal generator, like this one from R&S [Rohde Schwarz](http://www.rohde-schwarz.com/en/product/cmw270-productstartpage_63493-9552.html) (Warning- very expensive)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you application is an app to accurately measure wifi signal strength then you haven't provided enough information about your app. Do you really expect different functionality from your application if the signal strength attenuated? Or are you trying to assess performance issues?

Controlling signal strength accurately (in a controlled environment) must be done from the wireless access point. Some access point configurations allow you to control signal strength as suggested by Rsf.

Aluminum foil has a skin depth of about 100 µm and will will provide about 35% attenuation signals in the 1 MHz range (wifi). To completely block the signal you can build a Faraday cage (layers of brass screen seem to work best if you make it from scratch...commercial ones vary in price.

Comment: i updated my question sir please have a look on it sir

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an iOS6 device and are a registered developer, you can use the network link conditioner to simulate a large variety of network types. See [here](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/) for a detailed how to.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS ONLY. 
You can install on your MAC "Network Link Conditioner", it allows you to simulate different connection profiles (3g, DSL, Edge, WIFI average good or lossy connectivity, no connection). Once you select your profile, you need to connect your iOS phone to your MAC (hotspot wifi) and test your app.